# Arduino MQTT Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, mqtt

Is there a library to use MQTT with a bluetooth module (HC-06) instead of WiFi? If not is there a similar ready for use implementation of a publisher subscriber pattern available?

Answer (score 1):

MQTT is TCP/IP native. If you want to access it via Bluetooth, you need a gateway; a device that translate protocols. You need one for the specific protocols involved: MQTT, TCP/IP and Bluetooth.

Google "MQTT Bluetooth gateway" to find alternatives like this one:

[image]

> The iGS01 gateway listens for beacons, gets their advertising data and
>   forwards it on to your server or an IoT server via TCP, HTTP(S) or
>   MQTT. It can be used to feed back-end systems that report on the
>   presence or absence of iBeacon or Eddystone beacons or act on beacon
>   sensor (e.g. accelerometer, temperature, light, humidity) data.

[image]

> The gateway connects to your local 2.4GHz frequency band WiFi access
>   point and is managed via a web browser interface. It can  be connected
>   via WPS (press button on both the gateway and the WiFi access point).
>   It can also be managed via Telnet commands from other hardware (or a
>   human).
>
> For MQTT/MQTTS, the host, port, username, password and a root CA cert
>   can be provided.

There are also software only solutions available, but I didn't found a generic one, only specific for certain vendors.